# How to allow read-only access to specific Android apps?

Tags: internal-storage, external-sd, ram

I would like to manually disable writing access only, yet still allow reading to a selected application onto the internal storage or external SD card.
Android so far just allows allowing both or none via settings.

How do I allow just reading for a specific application?

Comment: Is your device rooted? Afraid without root access, a solution is unlikely.

Comment: Some are, some are not @izzy.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the reason you want the application to read but not write, maybe their is another solution.

Comment: @Zillinium It is an APK from the Internet, and I do not need it for write access but for reading.

Comment: So for example, something like an ebook reader ? requires reading books but doesn't require writing to them ? .... I'm not sure if you can separate the two permissions, You could for example, remove the buttons from the application that require write access.